# Randomly place n elements in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I need a boolean or binary numpy array size `(m,m)` with `n` True values scattered randomly.  I'm trying to make a random grid pattern.  I will have a `5x5` array with `3` True values over it and will sample at those points only.
Using random.choice I sometimes get more or less than the `3` desired True values.

```
for x in range(0,25):
    x = np.random.choice([True,False], p=[0.15,0.85])
```

Comment: Would be nice if you can explain your usecase with examples.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  Is this question unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it straightforwardly with shuffle:

```
n = 3; m = 5
x = [True] * n + [False] * (m * m - n)
np.random.shuffle(x)
result = np.mat(x).reshape(m, m)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with the optional argument `replace` set as `False` to have **`unique random`** IDs from `0` to `m*m-1` that could be set to `ones` in a `zeros` initialized `2D` array using [`linear indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) with [`np.put`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html). Thus, the implementation would look something like this -

```
m = 5; n = 3;
out = np.zeros((m,m),dtype=bool)
np.put(out,np.random.choice(range(m*m), n, replace=False),1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [54]: m = 5; n = 3;
    ...: out = np.zeros((m,m),dtype=bool)
    ...: np.put(out,np.random.choice(range(m*m), n, replace=False),1)
    ...: 

In [55]: out
Out[55]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Since it's a case of `linear indexing`, at the last step, you could also do -

```
out.ravel()[np.random.choice(range(m*m), n, replace=False)] = 1
```